# Windows 10 File Cloud / Sync Provider API - TransferData problem

Tags: winapi, onedrive, c++-winrt

I am building upon the [Cloud Mirror Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/CloudMirror) and having a similar issue to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60733034/cfapi-cloud-operation-is-invalid?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C7.1670)

Here is the test code involved:

```
        // When the client needs to fetch data from the cloud, this method will be called.
    // The FakeMirrorDataMover class does the actual work of copying files from
    // the "cloud" to the "client" and updating the transfer status along the way.
    void CALLBACK FakeCloudProvider::OnFetchData(
        _In_ CONST CF_CALLBACK_INFO* callbackInfo,
        _In_ CONST CF_CALLBACK_PARAMETERS* callbackParameters)
    {
        //FileCopierWithProgress::CopyFromServerToClient(callbackInfo, callbackParameters, ProviderFolderLocations::GetServerFolder());
    
            const UINT CHUNKSIZE = 48 * 1024 * 1024;
            UINT len;
            LONG64 offset = callbackParameters->FetchData.RequiredFileOffset.QuadPart;
            LONG64 requiredLength = callbackParameters->FetchData.RequiredLength.QuadPart;
            byte *buffer = new byte[CHUNKSIZE];
            FillMemory(buffer, CHUNKSIZE, (byte)0xA5);
    
            while (0 < requiredLength)
            {
                len = requiredLength < CHUNKSIZE ? requiredLength : CHUNKSIZE;
                if (0 != len % 4096)
                    len = 4096 * (len / 4096 + 1);
    
                Placeholders::TransferData(callbackInfo->TransferKey.QuadPart, buffer, offset, len, 0);
    
                requiredLength -= len;
                offset += len;
            }
    
            delete[] buffer;
    }

HRESULT Placeholders::TransferData(
    //_In_ CF_CONNECTION_KEY connectionKey,
    _In_ LONG64 transferKey,
    _In_reads_bytes_opt_(length.QuadPart) LPCVOID transferData,
    _In_ LONG64 startingOffset,
    _In_ LONG64 length,
    _In_ NTSTATUS completionStatus)
{
    CF_OPERATION_INFO opInfo = { 0 };
    CF_OPERATION_PARAMETERS opParams = { 0 };

    opInfo.StructSize = sizeof(opInfo);
    opInfo.Type = CF_OPERATION_TYPE_TRANSFER_DATA;
    opInfo.ConnectionKey = FakeCloudProvider::GetConnectionKey();
    opInfo.TransferKey.QuadPart = transferKey;
    opParams.ParamSize = CF_SIZE_OF_OP_PARAM(TransferData);
    opParams.TransferData.CompletionStatus = completionStatus;
    opParams.TransferData.Buffer = transferData;
    opParams.TransferData.Offset.QuadPart = startingOffset;
    opParams.TransferData.Length.QuadPart = length;

    winrt::check_hresult(CfExecute(&opInfo, &opParams));     
    return S_OK;
}
```

There is only one placeholder file created inside the sync root folder of ~ 9.3 GB size. After I create this I either double click it or right click and "always keep on this device" - same result.

The result being that after the last call to `TransferData` the Windows Explorer file progress gets stuck. It will eventually time out, I click on "try again", my breakpoints inside `OnFetchData()` get hit and file progress remains stuck. If I cancel the transfer then `onCancelFetchData()` gets called once as it should. Subsequent attempts to download the rest of the file *will no longer call `onFetchData()`*

If I comment out the `if (0 != len % 4096)      len = 4096 * (len / 4096 + 1);` part then I am getting the dreaded `0x8007017c the cloud operation is invalid` with the rest of the symptoms as above.

I have tried with a smaller ~ 9.3 MB file and it went fine... what else to try?

**edit**

The ~100MB and ~1GB sizes also working fine

Result of `CfExecute` calls:

```
//[...] same output for all previous offsets except for the last call
TransferData method - offset: 1298137088, length: 50331648, syncStatBeforeCall: null, syncStatAfterCall: null, hresult: 0
TransferData method - offset: 1348468736, length: 50331648, syncStatBeforeCall: null, syncStatAfterCall: null, hresult: 0
TransferData method - offset: 1398800384, length: 11265024, syncStatBeforeCall: null, syncStatAfterCall: null, hresult: 8007017c
```

As far as I can tell null is fine for `SyncStatus`:

> SyncStatus
>
> Note  This member is new for Windows 10, version 1803.
>
> The current sync status of the platform.
>
> The platform queries this information upon any failed operations on a
> cloud file placeholder. If a structure is available, the platform will
> use the information provided to construct a more meaningful and
> actionable message to the user. The platform will keep this
> information on the file until the last handle on it goes away. If
> null, the platform will clear the previously set sync status, if there
> is one.

**--edit--**

```
HRESULT Placeholders::Create(_In_ PCWSTR destPath,
                          _In_ PCWSTR fileName,
                          _In_ CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_FLAGS flags,
                          _In_ LONG64 fileSize,
                          _In_ DWORD fileAttributes,
                          _In_ LONG64  ftCreationTime,
                          _In_ LONG64  ftLastWriteTime,
                          _In_ LONG64  ftLastAccessTime,
                          _In_ LONG64  ftChangeTime)
{
    CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_INFO cloudEntry;
        
    cloudEntry.FileIdentity = fileName;
    cloudEntry.FileIdentityLength = (DWORD)((wcslen(fileName)+1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
    cloudEntry.RelativeFileName = fileName;
    cloudEntry.Flags = flags;
    cloudEntry.FsMetadata.FileSize.QuadPart = fileSize;
    cloudEntry.FsMetadata.BasicInfo.FileAttributes = fileAttributes;
    cloudEntry.FsMetadata.BasicInfo.CreationTime.QuadPart = ftCreationTime;
    cloudEntry.FsMetadata.BasicInfo.LastWriteTime.QuadPart = ftLastWriteTime;
    cloudEntry.FsMetadata.BasicInfo.LastAccessTime.QuadPart = ftLastAccessTime;
    cloudEntry.FsMetadata.BasicInfo.ChangeTime.QuadPart = ftChangeTime;

    if ((fileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0)
    {
        cloudEntry.Flags |= CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_FLAG_DISABLE_ON_DEMAND_POPULATION;
        cloudEntry.FsMetadata.FileSize.QuadPart = 0;
        cloudEntry.FileIdentity = nullptr;
    }

    try
    {
        wprintf(L"Creating placeholder for %s\n", fileName);
        winrt::check_hresult(CfCreatePlaceholders(destPath, &cloudEntry, 1, CF_CREATE_FLAG_NONE, NULL));
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // winrt::to_hresult() will eat the exception if it is a result of winrt::check_hresult,
        // otherwise the exception will get rethrown and this method will crash out as it should
        wprintf(L"Failed to create placeholder for %s with %08x\n", fileName, static_cast<HRESULT>(winrt::to_hresult()));
        // Eating it here lets other files still get a chance. Not worth crashing the sample, but
        // certainly noteworthy for production code
        return static_cast<HRESULT>(winrt::to_hresult());
    }

    return S_OK;
}

Create(_T("C:\\SyncRootDT"), _T("file1"), CF_PLACEHOLDER_CREATE_FLAG_MARK_IN_SYNC,
            10000000000, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 532657415, 532657415, 532657415, 532657415));
```

Comment: Have you checked the return value of [`CfExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/nf-cfapi-cfexecute#return-value) and the synchronization status(SyncStatus) of [`CF_OPERATION_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/cfapi/ns-cfapi-cf_operation_info). You can try to add error checking to locate the specific location of the error.

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT Thanks for the comment, please see the edit

Comment: `You can try to add error checking to locate the specific location of the error` - like how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I observe similar behaviour. The hydration of files up to 4Gb works fine, but files over 4Gb always stuck and failed with the 'Cloud operation is invalid' exception. I was able to overcome it with [this fix](https://github.com/ITHit/UserFileSystemSamples/blob/master/Windows/VirtualFileSystem/VirtualFile.cs#L49-L64) but instead of the CF_CALLBACK_PARAMETERS.FETCHDATA.RequiredLength and OptionalLength, I used a complete file length from CF_CALLBACK_INFO.FileSize. It looks like after a recent Windows update the OptionalLength is always zero.
My code is in .NET, but I guess you can easily translate it into C++:

```
// Use a complete file size in case the file is over 4Gb
if (callbackInfo.FileSize > 0x100000000)
{
    requiredLength = callbackInfo.FileSize;
}
```

Comment: It does the trick! You wouldn't know about the accompanying "RPC not available" would you ?...

Comment: What happens is the application that's behind file dehydration (like notepad if you open a huge 2G .txt file) just asks for a partial size (in the notepad case, it just asks for approx 1.5G because it probably doesn't know how to handle a bigger text). But if instead of double clicking on it, you copy that 2G .txt file, the cloud filter will eventually require all of it. So it's a choice to hydrate the file to the end, but it's not strictly necessary. If you don't, the cloud filter will complain about a timeout, but it's notepad's fault.